# How to know if the image path is relative?

Tags: javascript, html, path

In the following snippet, if I try to get the src using javascript

```
<img src="/assets/images/star.png" />
```

as

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(item => console.log(item.src))
```

It prints the `src` as `http://site-name-on-browser/assets/images/start.png`

Is there a way I could know if the image path is relative or not? Here while iterating I would never know this.

I was trying this :

```
if (img.src.match(/^\//)) {
     console.log("path is relative");
}
```

But this does not work since the browser returns the complete path even if the source code as the relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` to get the value of the element's attribute.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(item => console.log(item.getAttribute("src")))
```